# parsing through html with php

Tags: php

while working on facebook connect I have to retrieve an access token from a url ( it is not in the url itself but in the file lined to that url) so this is what I do

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".$facebook_app_id."&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/facebook/oauth/&client_secret=".$facebook_secret."&code=".$code;"

function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){ 
    $string = " ".$string; 
    $ini = strpos($string,$start); 
    if ($ini == 0) return ""; 
    $ini += strlen($start); 
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini; 
    return substr($string,$ini,$len); 
} 


$access_token = get_string_between(file_get_contents($url), "access_token=", "&expires=");
```

it looks ugly and clumsy is there a better way to do it ? thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the PHP function `parse_str`

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".$facebook_app_id."&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/facebook/oauth/&client_secret=".$facebook_secret."&code=".$code;

parse_str(file_get_contents($url));

echo $access_token;
```

From the PHP manual: [(link)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

> void parse_str  (  string $str  [,  array &$arr  ] )
>
> Parses str as if it were the query
>   string passed via a URL and sets
>   variables in the current scope.